# how to show count datewise

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
    I want to show count date wise query executed fine but count is showing 1 if date is same
```

where im stucking not understand
date format is : 2020-06-01 09:20:35.000
here is my query

```
    select count(lead_id_lms) as lead_id_count,date_entered from g_hdfclms where 
     cast(date_entered as date) between '2020-06-01' and '2020-06-24'
     group by date_entered
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want only the *date* and not the *time*:

```
select cast(date_entered as date) as date_only, count(lead_id_lms) as lead_id_count
from g_hdfclms
where cast(date_entered as date) between '2020-06-01' and '2020-06-24'
group by cast(date_entered as date);
```